# Aspas saindo no formato incorreto do JSON!

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Estou serializando um dicionário para JSON em Razor Pages, porém as aspas (`"`), estão saíndo como `&quot;`

**_Layout.cshtml (UTF-8)**

```
...
<body>
    ...
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "@context", "http://schema.org" },
            { "@type", "Organization" },
            { "name", "Swenity" },
            { "url", "http://swenity.com" },
            { "logo", "/ui/lib/image/platform/swenity/basicPlatformWhite.png" }
        })
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```

**Saída:**

```
{&quot;@context&quot;:&quot;http://schema.org&quot;,&quot;@type&quot;:&quot;Organization&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;HAHA&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://example.com&quot;,&quot;logo&quot;:&quot;http://example.com/image.png&quot;}
```

Como eu posso fazer com que elas saíam no formato correto? Como `"`

Comment: Dê um pouco de contexto. Onde a informação está sendo mostrada?

Comment: @LINQ atualizei, estou mostrando na _Layout.cshtml

Comment: E por onde você tá vendo a informação? Pelo "inspecionar elemento" do browser?

Comment: Sim, no Microsoft Edge estou vendo pelo (Inspecionar elemento e Depurador = "Exibir Origem"), no Google Chrome pelo (Inspecionar e Exibir código fonte da página)

Comment: Meu arquivo está codificado como `UTF-8`

Comment: Mas qual é objetivo disto?

Comment: Apenas representação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta em uma pergunta do SO inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331195/json-net-serialize-c-sharp-object-to-json-issue

Utilizando `@Html.Raw()` eu consigo ter a saída de forma correta sem problemas.

```
...
<body>
    ...
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "@context", "http://schema.org" },
            { "@type", "Organization" },
            { "name", "Swenity" },
            { "url", "http://swenity.com" },
            { "logo", "/ui/lib/image/platform/swenity/basicPlatformWhite.png" }
        }))
    </script>
    ...
```